# Website or Server down notification tools

Tags: email, web, push-notification, ping

We've some production and local development servers that we use to host database and web apps for our clients. Some of them are mapped as websites to client's domain (i.e. we've both web apps with url - http://71.22.33.xx/demo/login & http://order.clientweb.com/login)

> Recently one of our clients reported that the website is down it returns a
>   "Service Unavailable" error. Eventually it turned that
>   the server was not reachable via remote desktop and none of the
>   websites on that server were responsive! We had to ping the hosting
>   company to reboot the server after which it was back online.

We can't predict future situations but how to get notified when the website or the server is down? A simple way would be to ping 71.22.33.xx but I believe that's old school. Are there any tools (like [this](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/firefox.php)) which would not only monitor or eventually check the availability and most importantly mail the admin when it goes down.

I'm sure I'm not the first one with such requirement :-) Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664478/push-notification-if-web-server-goes-down). Some one please help ?

Thank you.

PS: Or do I've to write my own [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734059/program-that-sends-an-email-notification-if-url-is-down).

Comment: [Attomon](https://attomon.com)

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of products/services that can notify you if your website is down:

- [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Montastic](http://www.montastic.com/)
- [Pingdom](https://starthq.com/apps/pingdom)

Some provide more features than others so pick the solution most suitable for your needs.